# The SNMP of Weblogic 10.3 bind to localhost

Tags: weblogic, snmp

I am monitoring the Weblogic by SNMP in two servers. All the servers are solaris. One of the Weblogic is V12.1.1, another is V10.3.3. 
The SNMP in V12.1.1 is fine, but not work in V10.3.3.

When I use the ip address as the argument of snmpwalk for monitoring Weblogic 10.3.3, there is no response. It's only work for using 'localhost' as the argument of snmpwalk instead of ip address.

But the ip address work find for Weblogic 12.1.1.

Is the snmp bind to localhost in Weblogic 10.3.3. How can I　config it to ip address.

Thanks.

Comment: You can set the listen address and listen port in your server's configuration. Use the admin console and go to the Configuration/General tab to set them.
Also, don't forget to activate SNMP at the domain level.

Comment: I set the server's IP address in the weblogic console. It worked. Thank you.

It's a slight  different from other port when I used the netstat command. The other port is bind to *, only the snmp port bind to IP.